# Porting Razor RockStars to ServiceStack V4

Tags: servicestack

I'm currently looking at the [Razor Rockstars](https://github.com/ServiceStack/RazorRockstars) example project on github, to try and grasp how ServiceStack V4 and Razor is glued together.

I am specifically struggling with the following piece of code in the SS Razor demo:

```
SetConfig(new EndpointHostConfig {
           CustomHttpHandlers = {
                { HttpStatusCode.NotFound, new RazorHandler("/notfound") },
                { HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, new RazorHandler("/login") },
            }
        });
```

I know from the docs that EndpointHostConfig is now simply HostConfig, but I can't seem to locate the CustomHttpHandlers in the [Service Stack V4 release notes](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Release-Notes). Is there something obvious I'm missing?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The HostConfig is limited to configuration, in v4 most of the handlers that used to be in the Config have been moved to the AppHost, e.g:

```
this.CustomErrorHttpHandlers[HttpStatusCode.NotFound] = new RazorHandler("/notfound");
this.CustomErrorHttpHandlers[HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized] = new RazorHandler("/login");
```

Comment: Thanks too! Can you add this to the v4 release notes?